# Output Iterator in SuiteScript Map/Reduce Summarize Function

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm working on a map/reduce script to handle some automated billing processing. I run a search for invoices in the *GetInput* stage, group them by customer in the *Map* stage, and then create the payments in the *Reduce* stage. However, in the *Summarize* stage, only one key/value pair ever exists. So, I created a dummy test script to play with the functionality and figure it out, and kept running into the same problem.

Here's what I have for the testing script:

```
define(['N/search'], (search) => {

const getInputData = (inputContext) => {
    let filt = [
            ["trandate","on","3/29/2022"]
        ,   "and"
        ,   ["mainline","is","T"]
    ];
    let cols = [
            search.createColumn({ name : "tranid" })
        ,   search.createColumn({ name : "entity" })
        ,   search.createColumn({ name : "total" })
    ];
    let results;
    try {
        // custom search wrapper
        results = getSearchResults("invoice", filt, cols);
    }
    catch (err) {
        log.error({ title : "Error encountered retrieving invoices" , details : err });
    }
    
    return results;
}

const map = (mapContext) => {
    try {
        let data = JSON.parse(mapContext.value);
        let output = { key : "" , value : data };
        let rand = randomInt(0, 1); // custom random number generator
        if (rand === 0) {
            output.key = "FAILURE";
        }
        else {
            output.key = "SUCCESS";
        }
        mapContext.write(output);
    }
    catch (err) {
        log.error({ title : "Map Stage Error" , details : err });
    }
}

const reduce = (reduceContext) => {
    reduceContext.write({
            key : reduceContext.key
        ,   value : JSON.stringify(reduceContext.values)
    });
}

const summarize = (summaryContext) => {
    summaryContext.output.iterator().each((key, value) => {
        log.audit({ title : `summary -- ${key} -- ${typeof value}` , details : value });
    });
}

return {getInputData, map, reduce, summarize}

});
```

By all accounts, the summary logging should have two key entries to report, but only ever has one. In the test I've tried it both by marking values as either **SUCCESS** or **FAILURE** in the *Map* stage and then just passing it through the *Reduce* stage, and also by passing the values through the *Map* stage to be marked as **SUCCESS** or **FAILURE** in the *Reduce* stage and then passed on with the invoice record ID as the key. No matter what, the output iterator in the *Summarize* stage only ever reports back a single key. I've had this work correctly in one particular situation, but for the life of me I can't figure out what's different/wrong.

Any insights? Otherwise the only way I can think of to be able to propagate necessary data is to utilize the *'N/cache'* module, which does work pretty well but feels like it should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you need to `return true;` from the `each()` callback function, or it will stop processing.

```
const summarize = (summaryContext) => {
    summaryContext.output.iterator().each((key, value) => {
        log.audit({ title : `summary -- ${key} -- ${typeof value}` , details : value });
        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: Whadda ya know, that did the trick. I never saw that mentioned anywhere as being needed, but I see it in some of the examples floating around, once I went back to double check. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I handle errors in MP script by this way

```
summarize: function summarize(summarizeContext) {
        function handleErrorIfAny(summary)
        {
            var mapSummary = summary.mapSummary;
            var reduceSummary = summary.reduceSummary;

            handleErrorInStage('map', mapSummary);
            handleErrorInStage('reduce', reduceSummary);
        }
        function handleErrorInStage(stage, summary)
        {
            summary.errors.iterator().each(function(key, value){
                nLog.error('Failure in key ' + key, value);
                return true;
            });
        }
        handleErrorIfAny(summarizeContext);
    }
```